# Do I need to always create a constructor for objects in Java?

Tags: java, class, object, constructor

I have seen a lot of code that doesn't refer to any constructors. I have created code that doesn't contain constructors which seemingly defies the point of having one. Are there rules for when one needs to implement a constructor?

Comment: How about reading [straight from the horse's mouth](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html). I recommend reading the other trails as well.

Comment: And you don't need constructors if you don't use other classes. But i guess procedural programming in Java is not the way to go :)

Comment: Read up on the "default constructor".

Answer (score 2):

> You don't have to provide any constructors for your class, but you
>   must be careful when doing this. The compiler automatically provides a
>   no-argument, default constructor for any class without constructors.
>   This default constructor will call the no-argument constructor of the
>   superclass. In this situation, the compiler will complain if the
>   superclass doesn't have a no-argument constructor so you must verify
>   that it does. If your class has no explicit superclass, then it has an
>   implicit superclass of Object, which does have a no-argument
>   constructor.

As provided by the javaOO [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a class "A", and you don't create a constructor, a constructor:

```
public A(){
}
```

will be implicitly created, i.e. you won't actually see it. (thanks, @Steve Smith)

If you create any constructor, this default constructor will not be created. This is important when using certain design patterns like factory method and singleton.

If you create a private constructor:

```
private A(){
}
```

the default constructor (that is public) will not be created. This means that only inside the class A you can create instances of A. To export instances of A to other classes, you need to create them on static methods and return the references. This is employed on the Singleton pattern, for instance:

```
public A{
   private static A instance = new A();

   public static A getInstance(){
      return instance;
   }

   //the default public constructor will not be created
   private A(){
   }
}
```

Comment: To avoid confusion, it might be worth clarifying that it "will be implicitly created, i.e. you won't actually see it".

Comment: The singleton code is slightly wrong. It wouldn't have been wrong if it were implemented as a single-constant enum as we're supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, you HAVE to provide a constructor if you want to ensure that the instantiated object is initialised with certain data. For example, you might want to have a `Person` class which always has a valid first & last name as well as an age.

```
Person hugo = new Person("Hugo", "First", 25);
```

the constructor would then be

```
public Person(String first, String last, int age) {
    setFirst(first);
    setLast(last);
    setAge(age);
}

protected Person() {}
```

This way it is impossible to instantiate an empty `Person`.

Comment: Thanks, Paul, this makes sense.

Comment: "This way it is impossible to instantiate an empty Person" Except if you extend the class. The protected constructor should not be added here, this opens up the possibility of an "empty" `Person`.